# Open shift node.js - make it run a different start script on the startup

Tags: node.js, openshift, openshift-enterprise

I'm getting this error on the server because I've a different structure (webstorm configuration) for the startup scripts.

```
Error: Cannot find module '/var/lib/openshift/56c74bc61a003e5c2200015e/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:962:3
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 1
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
```

My package.json is (I've added "main": "./bin/www" manually)

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "main": "./bin/www",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Please advise that make open shift run above configuration.

**Edit**

Actually adding `"main": "./bin/www"` gave this error

```
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node ./bin/www'
Port 8080 is already in use
DEBUG: Program node ./bin/www exited with code 1
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node ./bin/www'
Port 8080 is already in use
DEBUG: Program node ./bin/www exited with code 1
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node ./bin/www'
Port 8080 is already in use
DEBUG: Program node ./bin/www exited with code 1
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node ./bin/www'
```

my www file

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openshift starts 'server.js' file be default. You can avoid this by adding `use_npm` file into openshift's markers directory. Or you can copy your `www` file contents to `server.js` and start with it.

Example contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('./app.js');
var debug = require('debug')('app:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
app.set('ip', ip);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port, ip);
```